# React hours to days timeline

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently still learning react js and have the below code which will list out the hours in a day, later on I will likely do something better with this; however I am struggling to get this to go further than 1 day and reset at midnight to 00:00 and continue correctly at the moment i get 00:00 -> 47:00

does anyone here understand the best way in order to take the below and have it essentially create 00 to 00 and repeat based on the number of days given?

CODE:

```
function TimeLine() {
  const hoursInDay = 24;
  const daysToTest = 2;
  
  const hours = new Array(hoursInDay * daysToTest)
    .fill(null)
    .map((item, index) => index);

  
  const timeLine = hours.map((item) => {
    return (
      <ul className="timeline__item">
        <li key={item}>{item}:00</li>
      </ul>
    );
  });

  return <div>{timeLine}</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [modulus (remainder)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) operator to "wrap" the hours at 24 (`item % 24`):

```
function TimeLine() {
  const hoursInDay = 24;
  const daysToTest = 2;
  
  const hours = new Array(hoursInDay * daysToTest)
    .fill(null)
    .map((item, index) => index);
  
  const timeLine = hours.map((item) => {
    return (
        <li key={item}>{item % 24}:00</li>
    );
  });

  return <ul>{timeLine}</ul>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<TimeLine />, document.body);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ah that simple omg i did not realise that and way over complicated the thought process (real life facepalm)

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use `Array.from` with a simple condition instead, so you would avoid one of the loops.

```js
const timeLine = () => {
  const hours = 24;
  const days = 2;
  
  const res = Array.from({ length: hours * days }, 
     (_, k) => k < hours ? k : k - (Math.floor(k / hours) * hours));
    
  return res;
};

console.log(timeLine());
```